# What is the role of the parameter 'selection' in sklearn.linear_model.Lasso

Tags: scikit-learn, lasso-regression

I wonder the role of the parameter 'selection' in the sklearn function sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.

I guess this parameter set the optimization way of Lasso solver, but I want to know exactly how it is works. I read the docs of this, but I didn't catch up this perfectly.

Could you explain this?

What is the different between selection = 'cyclic' and selection = 'random' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is between [coordinate descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent) and random coordinate descent. [In every iteration](https://xavierbourretsicotte.github.io/lasso_implementation.html) it cycles through features (i.e. coordinates) one at a time, minimizing the cost function with respect to each coordinate.

[Regular](https://slideplayer.com/slide/12055042/) coordinate descent cycles through all features:
[image]

Randomized chooses each feature at random:
[image]

[Here's](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f69242646d239d89a5713982946b8ffcf9d9/sklearn/linear_model/cd_fast.pyx#L167) it in sklearn.

Comment: Cool. I could know what coordinate descent is thanks to you! Thank you.